# How to remove White space on Images in Magento 2

Tags: themes, magento2

how can i remove the white spaces on pictures in Magento 2?

Thx

[image: Magento 2 White Spaces on pictures]

Answer (score 0):

you have more than one way.

The Problem:
The images are to small or the given size in your config is to big.

1. You have to edit the **view.xml**
   app/design/frontend/Themename/theme/etc/

Take the size (px) from your images and edit the given values in this file.

2. Use an image with a biger size.

I think you have to do the first way.
Otherwise you have to change all images and thats not the fastest way, right? =)

And dont forget to check your given/set image "attribut/role" in your product under "images and videos".
You can set an